# something weird when compare in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, compare, converters

first, sorry everyone because my bad at english. I have a simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    char ch = '1';  
    if (ch == (char)1) {
        cout << "Yes";
    }
    else {
        cout << "No";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

the weird thing is the console print No. Why the aren't equal?

Comment: `(char) 1` is not equal to `'1'`.

Comment: The character literal `'1'` has a numeric value of 49. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

Comment: @RetiredNinja It may have the value of `49`.  ASCII is not the only encoding allowed in C++

Comment: Because they aren't.  Technically, that's a characteristic of the C++ implementation's runtime character set, but none of the character sets in wide use encode the decimal digit characters with codes equal to the digit values they represent.  That would be especially problematic for `'0'`, whose numeric encoding as 0 would make it a string terminator.

Comment: On the other hand, `'1' - '0'` is 1. That's how you convert digit characters to the value that the digit represents.

Comment: `std::cout << char(1);` -- If you're working with the IBM character set code page 437, you get a funny face character on output, not `1`.

Answer (score 2):

`ch` contains the character code for the character `'1'`.  Assuming ASCII encoding, the value of this code is 49.  This is not equal to 1, so the condition is false.

Casting the value 1 to `char` does *not* convert it to a character encoding.

For the condition to be true, you need to use the character constant to do the comparison.

```
if (ch == '1') {
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because (char)1 is not '1' but represents 'start of heading'. Hence your output became No.

Comment: I think this comment could use an explanation of what "start of heading" means exactly.

Answer (score 0):

`(char) 1` will convert 1 from decimal to ascii code 1 that equals with [start of heading]
you can convert '1' ascii code that is 49.